# how to read text file from assets in fragment?

Tags: android, file, text, fragment, assets

How should i read text file from `assets` ?

I am using fragment here.
It looks like i cant use anything with `getAssets();` because then i get: `Error:(88, 37) error: cannot find symbol method getAssets()` The goal is to be able to read/write several strings.

For example:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = assetManager.open("hello.txt");
}
catch (IOException e){
    Log.e("message: ",e.getMessage());
}
```

I would like to be able to read values in one place, then write values in another place of the code. Please help, i'am desperate, nothing that i have found online is working

Comment: You need a context to call that method. You may call getActivity from the fragment, to get that context.

Comment: still no idea how that works

Answer (score 6):

```
 public String loadTextFileFromAsset() {
    String content = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getContext().getAssets().open("dora.txt");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        content = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return content;
}
```

Add textfile (say dora.txt) in src/main/assets folder

Answer (score 2):

`getAssets()` is a method on `Context`. You can call `getActivity()` on your `Fragment`, then call `getAssets()` on it.

Comment: thanks, but is there a proper way to read values from text file and save them in my variables?

Comment: @user2864772: I have no idea what your "variables" are. An asset is not strictly a "text file" on the Android device -- you simply get an `InputStream` on its contents using `open()` on an `AssetManager`. You then use that `InputStream` using standard Java file I/O.

Comment: There are numerous ways to read values from a file. But as we do not know how you build up your file we cannot advice..

Comment: i intend to write 7 string values. line by line. example would look like this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-AvGwqzCuxKc/U5vqRUglUOI/AAAAAAAADsc/bJFEtMPhdOs/s1600/text-file.png

Comment: @user2864772: You cannot write to an asset. You can read from an asset, but you will have to write somewhere else, such as a file on [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: it appears to be true.. maybe someone would still help me to read line by line when i get get over this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class DummyDataReader {
    Context context;

    public DummyDataReader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String ReadTextFromFile(String file) {
        String data = "";
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open(file);
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader in =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str);
            }
            in.close();
            data = buf.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

To read file use this function

```
String response = new DummyDataReader(getActivity()).ReadTextFromFile("hello.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Devendra Dora's example above I found that asset subdirectory names that start with an uppercase letter will not work. Changing subdirectory names to all lowercase worked like a charm. Android Studio 3.1.2 did not complain about the uppercase naming I had been using (to no avail) but this example helped me to resolve my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tab3 extends  Fragment {
    private TextView textView;
    private StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        String content = null;
        try {

            InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("i.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            content = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("error","error");
        }


            TextView output= (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            output.setText(content);

        }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_3, container, false);
         return rootView;
    }
}
```

That is what I do in a tabbed activity.

---

Attention put your asset file in :\appname\app\src\main\assets